# Year, Month, Days, hours between two dates

Tags: c#

I need to find the difference between two dates and show the results 
in  year,month, day and hour format for e.g 1 year 2 months 6 days and 4 hour.

How can i do this. Day and hour is very simple. but year and month is giving me a hard time.

I need the result to be 100% accurate...we can't assume 30 days per month or 356 per year.
please help Thanks.

Comment: Datetime supports +,-,<,>,= operators...! You can do date1-date2

Comment: What value should Months have when there are 60 days between the two dates? Give us some examples of inputs and the required matching output.

Comment: I we provide two DateTime and result a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get accurate number of Years, Months and actually also days (because `Timespan` `Days` and `TotalDays` are number of days from between two dates) is to use the `AddYears`, `AddMonths` and `AddDays` method respectively.

I'll create a Class here named `DateDiff` that will compute the number of Years, Months and Days between two dates. However, I will give you only the code (and algo) for computing Years difference because if you know the Years you will know also how to do the Months and the Days. And of course so that you yourself has something to work on also ;-)

Here's the code:

**DateDiff Class:**

```
class DateDiff
 {
    public DateDiff(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        GetYears(startDate, endDate); // Get the Number of Years Difference between two dates
        GetMonths(startDate.AddYears(YearsDiff), endDate); // Getting the Number of Months Difference but using the Years difference earlier
        GetDays(startDate.AddYears(YearsDiff).AddMonths(MonthsDiff), endDate); // Getting the Number of Days Difference but using Years and Months difference earlier
    }
    void GetYears(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int Years = 0;
        // Traverse until start date parameter is beyond the end date parameter
        while (endDate.CompareTo(startDate.AddYears(++Years))>=0) {}
        YearsDiff = --Years; // Deduct the extra 1 Year and save to YearsDiff property
    }
    void GetMonths(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
      // Provide your own code here
    }
    void GetDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
      // Provided your own code here
    }

    public int YearsDiff { get; set; }
    public int MonthsDiff { get; set; }
    public int DaysDiff { get; set; }
 }
```

You could test the code from the Main like this:

**Test the Code:**

```
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 8, 0, 0);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2013, 11, 4, 8, 0, 0);
    DateDiff dateDifference = new DateDiff(date1, date2);

    Console.WriteLine("Years = {0}, Months = {1}, Days = {2}", dateDifference.DiffYears, dateDifference.DiffMonths, dateDifference.DiffDays);
```

Comment: can you add code for GetMonths and GetDays method, because i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Look into DateTime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

You can do things like

```
new DateTime(10,14,2012) - new DateTime(10,12,2012) ect..
```

Comment: `4` upvotes? `DateTime` doesn't have a constructor takes `string` as a parameter. Did you tried it before posting your answer?

Comment: You're right. Updated to reflect correct params. I was of the Powershell Get-Date which can take a string as an arg.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeSpan = dateTime2 - dateTime1;
var years = timeSpan.Days / 365;
var months = (timeSpan.Days - years * 365)/30;
var days = timeSpan.Days - years * 365 - months * 30;
// and so on
```

Comment: Are all months 30 days?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd we try to calculate difference in inconstant units(years - 365\366, month - 28\29\30\31), anyway we will have some kind of assumption

Comment: @sh1ng - Yes, so we need to get the assumptions in line with the requirements before answering the question.

Comment: i can do this but i need the results to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @Taufiq what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
        DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan dif = newDate - oldDate;

        int leapdays = GetLeapDays(oldDate, newDate);

        var years = (dif.Days-leapdays) / 365;
        int otherdays = GetAnOtherDays(oldDate, newDate , years);
        int months = (int)((dif.Days - (leapdays + otherdays)- (years * 365)) / 30);
        int days = (int)(dif.Days - years * 365 - months * 30) - (leapdays + otherdays);

        Console.WriteLine("Edad es {0} años, {1} meses, {2} días", years, months, days) ;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int GetAnOtherDays(DateTime oldDate, DateTime newDate, int years) {
        int days = 0;

        oldDate = oldDate.AddYears(years);
        DateTime oldDate1 = oldDate.AddMonths(1);

        while ((oldDate1.Month <= newDate.Month && oldDate1.Year<=newDate.Year) || 
            (oldDate1.Month>newDate.Month && oldDate1.Year<newDate.Year)) {
            days += ((TimeSpan)(oldDate1 - oldDate)).Days - 30;
            oldDate = oldDate.AddMonths(1);
            oldDate1 = oldDate.AddMonths(1);
        }

        return days;
    }

    public static int GetLeapDays(DateTime oldDate, DateTime newDate)
    {
        int days = 0;

        while (oldDate.Year < newDate.Year) {
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(oldDate.Year)) days += 1;
            oldDate = oldDate.AddYears(1);
        }

        return days;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some comments or explanations to your code.

Comment: It is the same as stated 'sh1ng', however this code adds the days of leap years between two dates. Also add the days of the months with 28 and 31 days.